# CCF Plot Function loop

Tags: r

I have created a function that turns my data frame into a time series list, but Im having trouble creating a ccf function that would pair one variable within the list to all other variables within the list and create ccf plots with a max lag of 24 based off of those pairings

Function for turning list of data frame into a time series

```
nonresi_list <- list(nonresii)
lst3 <- lapply(resii_list, function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) ts(y, start = min(as.numeric(row.names(x))),
                                  end = max(as.numeric(row.names(x)))))
  x})
str(lst3)
```

Currently im utilizing the below function to create CCF plots but its tedious when you have multiple variables

```
Sales1 <- lst3[[1]][[5]]

ccf(lst3[[1]][[8]],Sales1,lag.max=24 , main="Sales & NSA")
ccf(lst3[[1]][[9]],Sales1,lag.max=24 , main="Sales & Total")
ccf(lst3[[1]][[10]],Sales1,lag.max=24 , main="Sales & X1 Unit")
ccf(lst3[[1]][[11]],Sales1,lag.max=24 , main="Sales & X5 or more units")
ccf(lst3[[1]][[12]],Sales1,lag.max=24 , main="Sales & Northeast Total")
ccf(lst3[[1]][[13]],Sales1,lag.max=24 , main="Sales & Northeast 1 Unit")
ccf(lst3[[1]][[14]],Sales1,lag.max=24 , main="Sales & Midwest Total")
```

Any insights will help

Comment: It would be useful to have some example data, and also what you envision the final outcome to be.

Comment: I just want multiple ccf plots I don't want to run one line after another but ill fix it